# Variable code coverage threshold with sbt-scoverage

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, scoverage

I'm using [sbt-scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) plugin for measure the code (statement) coverage in our project. Because of months of not worriying about the coverage and our tests we decided to set a threshold for having a minimum coverage percentage: *if you are writing code at least try to leave the project with the same coverage percentage as when you've find it*. *e.g. if you've started your feature branch with a project having 63% of coverage you have, after finishing your feature, to leave the same coverage value*.

With this we want to ensure a gradual adoption of better practices instead of setting a fixed coverage value (something like `coverageMinimum := XX`).

Having said that, I'm considering the possibility of storing the last value of the analysis in a file and then compare that with a new execution, triggered by the developer.

Another option that I'm considering is to retrieve this value from our SonarQube server based on the data stored there.

My question is: Is there a way to do a thing like this with sbt-scoverage? I've dug into the docs and their Google Groups forum but I can't find something about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`coverageMinimum` setting value doesn't have to be constant, you can write any function dynamically returning it, eg:

`coverageMinimum := {
      val tmp = 2 + 4
      10 * tmp // returns 60 :)
    }`